# Why update picture doesn't detect file uploaded?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, image-uploading

I am using laravel 5 to create an edit form for a profile and can update picture in the form.

I want to store a new image in edit form. I use this code in edit.blade to get the image by user.

**View:**

```
{!! Form::model($dataItemregistration,['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['Modul\ProfilController@update', $dataItemregistration->ItemRegistrationID, 'files' => true] ]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3"> 
            {{ Form::label('pic', 'Gambar (Saiz gambar, 250x300px)') }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            {!! Form::file('gambar', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-lg-10 text-center">
   {!! link_to(URL::previous(),'Back', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-md']) !!}
   {{ Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $valueitemregistrations = Itemregistration::find($id);

    $this->validate($request,['gambar' => 'max:100000',]);
    if ($request->hasFile('gambar')) {
        // Get the file from the request
        $file = $request->file('gambar');
        // Get the contents of the file
        $content = $file->openFile()->fread($file->getSize());

        $valueitemregistrations->Picture = $content;
        $valueitemregistrations->update();

        if($valueitemregistrations) {
            return redirect('profil');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();
        }
    } else { 
        echo "testing";
    }
}
```

When I try to upload and update, it goes to echo "testing". It doesn't detected any files uploaded..

I had been using the same code for add.blade and it works.

Is it related to route path or else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when your HTML form doesn't have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

In this case the cause is `'files' => true` being part of the wrong array inside `Form::model()`; it's *inside* the `'action'` array when it should be *outside*. Try this:

```php
Form::model($dataItemregistration, [
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'action' => ['Modul\ProfilController@update', $dataItemregistration->ItemRegistrationID],
    'files' => true,
]);
```

Comment: You are brilliant..i have tried for days finding the problem..Thank you for your time and helping me... I have accepted your answer.